# how does RSA distribute keys to the sender and receiver?

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, encryption-asymmetric, secret-key

I'm working on a cryptography project that involes using RSA encryption algorithm, i have implemented the RSA algorithm and understand it, but how can i securely send the private key to the receiver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using asymmetric encryption you NEVER send the private key to the receiver. The receiver has your public key to decrypt your message encrypted with your private key.

Other way could be that you encrypt with the receivers public key and only he can decrypt the message with his private key.

So asymmetric encryption means to NEVER give your private key of hand.

Comment: So you keep youre decryption key private, send your encryption key to the receiver, he uses it to encrypt the message, then sends it back!

Comment: You keep your private key and send the public key to the other side. Any key of that can be used for encryption or decryption.

Answer (score 0):

In a **private-key cryptosystem**, no matter how complex the encryption and decryption scheme is, it is required that the sender and the receiver both agree on the scheme before they can use it to communicate. This is the fundamental problem of cryptography that RSA and other **public-key cryptosystem** tries to solve.

In RSA, the receiver generates a public key *(N, e)* and a private key *d* using two very large primes, so large that their product is very difficult to factor. (You can refer to the details of key generation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem))) The key difference of RSA with the aforementioned private-key algorithm is that *anyone* can encrypt a message using the public key generated by the receiver and send it to *anyone*, but only the receiver, with the private key, can decrypt the message. For this reason, RSA is often called an **asymmetric cryptosystem**.